# How do I return a reference to a bool from a function?

Tags: rust, boolean, traits

I was working on a bitboard implementation and was trying to implement the index trait but couldn't return value `&bool` because this creates a temp value which could not be returned. Is there any way I could return a `&bool` in another way?

```rust
use std::ops::Index;

pub struct Bitboard(usize);

impl Index<usize> for Bitboard {
    type Output = bool;

    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &(self.0 & (1 << index) != 0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let board = Bitboard(0b000_000_000);
    // bit:                          ^
    println!("{}", board[0]);
    // false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I could return a &bool in another way?

For arbitrary types returning a reference to a generated value would not be possible without leaking memory. But since there are only two distinct bool values, you could create them as static variables and return references to those:

```
static TRUE: bool = true;
static FALSE: bool = false;
// return &TRUE and &FALSE from index()
```

But it gets even easier because Rust treats a simple `&true` and `&false` as if you did just that, so this compiles:

```
fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &bool {
    if self.0 & (1 << index) != 0 {
        &true
    } else {
        &false
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e486683c80663009de0bc333e6af6653)

The borrow checker allows returning `&TRUE` and `&true` because those expressions produce references with `'static` lifetime. Such references can be coerced to references of any other lifetime, including the lifetime of `&self` as required by the signature of `Index::index()`.

Comment: Just for curiosity, I checked whether the compiler optimizes this away... [It does](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/Mcv5PYv97). Compilers are smart today.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That's so cool, I didn't expect that it would. Note that it already does so at `opt-level=1`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Given that the implementation is "visible" (inlinable) to the compiler, I'd kind of expect it to not be thrown off by the use of references. I find it more impressive that it optimized even my original idea of using explicit statics: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/7q8dMvTjo

Comment: @user4815162342 It's funny that the generated assembly is 100% identical apart of the fact that the statics are now labeled. Really shows you how it works behind the scenes.

Comment: I more surprise about this `.zero   1` ^^

Comment: @user4815162342 Explicit non-mut static (without interior mutability) are really the same as static-promoted ones, no reason the compiler will be able to optimize one but not the other.